# IIS URL Rewrite Rule Excluding Multiple Files

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have an IIS URL Rewrite rule that forces HTTPS unless that page is a healthcheck.html (which is over port 80). This works like a charm as I use the match URL logic as follows:

```
<match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
```

However, I need to exclude not just this page but a second file named OtherCheck.aspx in a directory named Dir1

I have not found any instances where others have excluded two files, especially one that is not in the root. Is it possible to have two filename exclusions? I tried this but it did not work:

```
<match url="healthcheck.html&/Dir1/OtherCheck.aspx" negate="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File and folder structure:
    s1(root folder):

healthcheck.html(file)

s2(subfolder):

page1.html(file)

You could use below url rewrite rule to exclude multiple files:

```
 <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS multiple file" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/s2/page1.html" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
   </rule>
```

https redirect:

[image]

exclude file:
[image]
[image]

**Note:
You could set file and folder name as per your requirement.**

Regards,
Jalpa

Comment: Makes complete sense. Excellent example and structure. As this was an Azure VM behind a AppGateway, I also needed to add <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />